# Sleep/Dream and Logical Decisions

Tags: cognitive-psychology, neuroscience, sleep, dreams

I discovered that sleep tends to mitigate the 'stress' that one gets by trying to deal with logical problems like work related tasks and general daily life tasks. Does sleep do this by removing the tendency for human to think logically as when we see dreams, they are highly illogical such as "fork made with orange peels!"

Is it the fact that in sleep the parts associated with stress i.e. logical reasoning part of the brain is being shutoff that results in weird dream contents?

Comment: Welcome to the Psychology and Neuroscience forum.  There is an expectation that individuals evidence basic enquiry on their topic prior to posting.  It is also helpful to the reader if you provide references to the prior research.  In this instance, are you able to shed light on how you discovered that sleep mitigates stress?  Is this personal experience or is it widely observed?

Comment: @TonyMobbs Thanks for the wishes. As per your question, its a personal experience that sleep mitigates stress. I will look into the references later today and update.

Comment: Well, logical reasoning is impaired by stress, but the dreams are hard to define. No one knows for sure what they are. In my view they are images of reprocessing the prior experience and can recombine in ways that logic would not allow. Therefore one could say dreams are essential for creativity and memory reconsolidation. The curious bit is - they occur even when you think in the morning you did not have any.

Comment: @r0berts I agree with you. But can you explain how are dreams essential for creativity and memory reconsolidation, as they are mostly illogical and even the logic part is what you already know, so I am not sure how they can improve my creativity skills.

Comment: As far as we can tell, dreams are present not only in humans, therefore they must be an evolutionarily very old mechanism that has gone on and on. I do not think, though, that you can "improve" your dreams and therefore you cannot say that you will improve your creativity. All I can say is that if we view creativity as spotting a useful/nice thing emerging out of chaos, then having had good sleep will definitely help this. However I know a person who may answer better, so I will ask.

Comment: @r0berts +1 for mentioning "creativity as spotting nice thing emerging out of chaos, then having good sleep with definitely help this" as it goes with the saying "lets sleep over it" which basically means if you have worked out a problem that is hard and still cant figure out, then a good sleep can help tackling the problem next day, which could be the creativity part you are referring to. I will wait for what the person you know have to say.

Comment: I will post when I have an answer, but in the meantime this is to say that while we sleep, processing in the brain/mind goes on. And part of that is dreams, so it would seem.